# Como pegar o número do span por um ID

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho a seguinte situação:

```
<span class="integral" id="precoVinho01">
   <span data-attr="Integer">100</span>
   <span data-attr="Decimal">,99</span>
</span>
```

Como faço para conseguir coletar apenas o **100,99**?

Tentei das seguintes maneiras:

```
$('#precoVinho01').find("span").each(function(index) {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).replaceWith(text);
 });
// Não funcionou, pois apagou o span inteiro, logo, perdeu a referencia data-attr para aparecer o número.
```

E tentei desta maneira também.

```
var price01 = $('#precoVinho01').html().replace(/[^\d]+/g,'').replace(',', '.');

// Não funcionou, pois o numero virou 10099, e quando tentei colocar toFixed para ter o decimal

var price01 = $('#precoVinho01').html().replace(/[^\d]+/g,'').toFixed(2).replace(',', '.');

//não funcionou
```

Agradeço a ajuda =)

Comment: É `10,99` ou é `100,99`?

Comment: 100,99 * , ajustei :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em vanilla javascript você pode utilizar a propriedade [`innerText`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-innertext-idl-attribute) do elemento `<span>`.

```js
let span = document.getElementById("precoVinho01");
console.log(span.innerText.replace(/\s/g, ''))
```

```html
<span class="integral" id="precoVinho01">
   <span data-attr="Integer">100</span>
   <span data-attr="Decimal">,99</span>
</span>
```

Com JQuery use o método [`text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/)

```js
console.log($("#precoVinho01").text().replace(/\s/g, ''))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="integral" id="precoVinho01">
   <span data-attr="Integer">100</span>
   <span data-attr="Decimal">,99</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Funcionou muito... obrigado!
Usei o método JQuery.
Tem alguma explicação do porque que .text funcionou e .html não?

Comment: Porque a função text() é uma abstração sobre a propriedade [`innerText`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-innertext-idl-attribute) e segundo o manual `innerText` retorna o conteúdo do texto do elemento "como renderizado" e `html()` retorna o HTML do elemento.